# thread a cylinder through a torus in powerpoint

Tags: office365, powerpoint

I can draw a cylinder and a torus; but how to make the cylinder look like it is threaded through the torus? I can only get the cylinder or torus to be on top.

i.e. something like this: [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can cut out part of the torus in the back by making a rectangle go over that part, selecting both the rectangle and torus, then going to Merge Shapes--> subtract. This will cut out the part of the torus in the back that the cylinder will go through. Then make the torus on top and it will look like the cylinder is threaded through the ring.